# .datapivotfield.orientation = xlhidden does not work

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, hidden-field

I have a vba  code which checks all the pivots in specified worksheets to add a range of pivotfield to the values/data section of the pivot because the pivot headers change every 4 weeks.

I have 6 pivots where this code works perfectly, but 2 pivots where I keep getting an error. I have tried to adjust the code but was not succesfull. I used this code to find the type for this pivot field as I thought it should be data, but it turns out to be *'hidden'*:

```
Set pvtTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PivotTable 
Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("ORDER_DATE") 
Select Case pvtField.Orientation 
 Case xlHidden 
 MsgBox "Hidden field" 
 Case xlRowField 
 MsgBox "Row field" 
 Case xlColumnField 
 MsgBox "Column field" 
 Case xlPageField 
 MsgBox "Page field" 
 Case xlDataField 
 MsgBox "Data field" 
End Select
```

I then checked this code on comparable fields in the pivots where it is working perfectly, expecting it would be data fields, but again it were hidden fields. I therefore do not understand what is different in these 2 pivots that makes my code not work compared to the pivots where the code works perfectly.

This is the code for the pivots where it is not working:

```
Sub AddAllFieldsValues_blad1()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iColEnd As Long
Dim sheetnames As Variant
Dim I As Variant

With Sheets("blad1")
    For Each pt In Sheets("blad1").PivotTables
       With pt
        .ManualUpdate = True
            .DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
            iCol = 11
                With .PivotFields(iCol)
                  If .Orientation = 0 Then
                      .Orientation = xlDataField
                  End If
                End With
        .ManualUpdate = False
        pt.PivotCache.refresh
        End With
    Next pt
End With
End Sub
```

I only need the pivot to have 1 pivot field in the values section.

When I execute this code, I get this error:
[image: pivotfield-error.png]

error 1004: 
propery orientation of class pivotfield cannot be set

And this line is marked when I click 'solve error' (or what it is called in english):

```
.DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
```

I do not understand why because it works perfectly for the other pivots in the worksheet. The only thing that is different is that for those pivots, the code is slightly different:

```
Sub AddAllFieldsValues()
Dim pt As pivottable
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iColEnd As Long
Dim sheetnames As Variant
Dim I As Variant

sheetnames = Array("data pivots euros", "data pivots category - euros", "data pivots units", "data pivots category - units")

For I = LBound(sheetnames) To UBound(sheetnames)

With Sheets(sheetnames(I))
    For Each pt In Sheets(sheetnames(I)).PivotTables
       With pt
        .ManualUpdate = True
            .DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
            iCol = 12
           iColEnd = .PivotFields.Count - 4

            For iCol = 12 To iColEnd
                With .PivotFields(iCol)
                  If .Orientation = 0 Then
                      .Orientation = xlDataField
                  End If
                End With
            Next iCol
        .ManualUpdate = False
        pt.PivotCache.refresh
        End With
    Next pt
End With
Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataPivotField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.datapivotfield) property is buggy, as it only works,
when your pivottable already has **at least 2 datafields**!

If you want to remove each datafield first, then replace the line

```
.DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
```

by this:

```
Dim df as PivotField
For Each df In .DataFields
    df.Orientation = xlHidden
Next df
```

Comment: Ah, exactly the difference! I want only one field in de values section where the other pivots have about 112 fields in the values section.

Comment: in this case, I have only one datafield so I removed the loop and specified the specific datafield to 11 (which is the data field I want to use. For the other pivots, the pivotfield loop works perfect for me now. Perhaps it could be more efficient, but because the fields from number 4 to 112 change every 4 weeks where fields 4, 5, 6 and 7 are not available anymore and at the back 4 new fields are added.

Comment: Then everything is fine (and I'll remove my "further remarks"). It's quite okay to remove and add many datafields - I just thought that was not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but if anyone looks i believe this replicates what the question asks.

> ```
> Dim xPivot As PivotTable
> 'setting exact pivot table also ensuring its targeting the correct sheet
> Set xPivot = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("Pivot_Table_Name")
> 'change "values" as required to view data fields/row fields etc
> 'change "Field Name" to match the value name
> xPivot.PivotFields("Values").PivotItems("FieldName").Visible = False
> ```